# Codeigniter custom search function issue

Tags: php, codeigniter, search, filter

Hello I am writing an php application and currently I'm stuck at a method that retrives flights from the database and applies diffrent filters to it. There are no problems when I initially load the page without any filters applied, all records from DB are loaded as expected. Then again everything as expected when I use "Departure Airport" or "Arrival Airport" filters along with "Bookable Only" filter.

It is whole of another story when you try to use "Bookable Only" filter on its own, it doesn't load any records from database. That's the same with "Aircraft" filter, doesn't work on its own and with "Bookable Only" filter but works when combined with both or either one of Airport filters + "Bookable Only" filter

**Schedules_model.php**

```
public function getFilteredSchedule($available, $departureICAO, $arrivalICAO, $specificAircraftId)
{
    $this->db->select('*'); 

    if($departureICAO != FALSE) {
        $this->db->where('departureICAO', $departureICAO);
    }
    if($arrivalICAO != FALSE) {
        $this->db->where('arrivalICAO', $arrivalICAO);
    }
    if($specificAircraftId != FALSE) {
        $this->db->where('aircraftId', $specificAircraftId);
    }

    $schedules = $this->db->where('active', 1)
                  ->order_by('id', 'asc')
                  ->get('schedules')
                  ->result_array();

    $schedulesAvailable = array();

    if($available === TRUE) {

        echo 'work';

        foreach($schedules as $key => $schedule) {

            if($this->RebuildVA->mustBeAtDepartureAirport()) {
                if($this->Aircrafts->isAtAirport($schedule['aircraftId'], $schedule['departureICAO'])) {
                    $schedulesAvailable[$key] = $schedule;
                } else { 
                    break;
                }
            } else {
                $schedulesAvailable[$key] = $schedule;
            }

            if(!$this->RebuildVA->allowMultipleAircraftBookings()) {
                if(!$this->Aircrafts->isBooked($schedule['aircraftId'])) {
                    $schedulesAvailable[$key] = $schedule;
                } else { 
                    break;
                }
            } else {
                $schedulesAvailable[$key] = $schedule;
            }

            if(!$this->RebuildVA->allowMultiplePilotBookings()) {
                if(!$this->Pilots->hasBookedFlight($this->session->userdata('pilotId'))) {
                    $schedulesAvailable[$key] = $schedule;
                } else { 
                    break;
                }
            } else {
                $schedulesAvailable[$key] = $schedule;
            }
        }
    } else {
        $schedulesAvailable = $schedules;   
    }       

    return $schedulesAvailable;
}
```

**schedules.php**

```
public function search()
{

    $this->data['pageTitle'] = 'Schedule Search';
    $this->data['pageDisplayedTitle'] = 'Schedule Search';

    $available = (bool) $this->input->post('available');

    $this->data['schedules'] = $this->Schedules->getFilteredSchedule($available, $this->input->post('departureICAO'), $this->input->post('arrivalICAO'), $this->input->post('aircraftId'));

    $airportsList = $this->Airports->getAllAirports(TRUE, TRUE); // Get set of all active airports
    $aircraftsList = $this->Aircrafts->getAllAircrafts(TRUE, TRUE); // Get set of all active airports

    // Prepare form inputs
    $this->data['departureICAO'] = array(
        'name'  => 'departureICAO',
        'id'    => 'departureICAO',
        'selected' => $this->input->post('departureICAO'),
        'options' => $airportsList,
    );      
    $this->data['arrivalICAO'] = array(
        'name'  => 'arrivalICAO',
        'id'    => 'arrivalICAO',
        'selected' => $this->input->post('arrivalICAO'),
        'options' => $airportsList,
    );
    $this->data['aircraftId'] = array(
        'name'  => 'aircraftId',
        'id'    => 'aircraftId',
        'selected' => $this->input->post('aircraftId'),
        'options' => $aircraftsList,
    );  
    $this->data['available'] = array(
        'name'  => 'available',
        'id'    => 'available',
        'checked' => set_checkbox('available', $this->input->post('available'), FALSE),
        'value' => TRUE,
    );

    $this->load->view('schedules/scheduleSearch', $this->data); 
}
```

I tried debugging everything and following the process step by step as well as trial and error method but none give expected effects. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By trial and error method I have found some kind of a work around that some how does the job. If anyone has any suggestions regarding it or how I could improve it, please feel free, as I am looking for performance in the app.

The required changes were in the Model:

```
public function getFilteredSchedule($available, $departureICAO, $arrivalICAO, $specificAircraftId)
{
    $this->db->select('*'); 

    if($departureICAO != FALSE) {
        $this->db->where('departureICAO', $departureICAO);
    }
    if($arrivalICAO != FALSE) {
        $this->db->where('arrivalICAO', $arrivalICAO);
    }
    if($specificAircraftId != FALSE) {
        $this->db->where('aircraftId', $specificAircraftId);
    }

    $schedules = $this->db->where('active', 1)
                  ->order_by('id', 'asc')
                  ->get('schedules')
                  ->result_array(); 

    $schedulesAvailable = array();

    // Check if any of the filters is required
    if(!$this->RebuildVA->mustBeAtDepartureAirport() && $this->RebuildVA->allowMultipleAircraftBookings() && $this->RebuildVA->allowMultiplePilotBookings()) {
        $schedulesAvailable = $schedules;
    // Check if only bookable flights has been checked
    } elseif($available === TRUE) {
        foreach($schedules as $key => $schedule) {

            // Allow multiple schedule bookings

            // Check if the aircraft must be at departure airport
            if($this->RebuildVA->mustBeAtDepartureAirport()) {
                if($this->Aircrafts->isAtAirport($schedule['aircraftId'], $schedule['departureICAO'])) {
                    $schedulesAvailable[$key] = $schedule;
                } else {
                    // Check if use of other aircraft of same type is allowed
                    if($this->RebuildVA->allowOtherAircraftUse()) {
                        if($this->Aircrafts->aircraftTypeAtAirport($schedule['aircraftId'], $schedule['departureICAO'])) {
                            $schedulesAvailable[$key] = $schedule;
                        } else {
                            unset($schedulesAvailable[$key]);
                            continue;
                        }
                    } else {
                        unset($schedulesAvailable[$key]);
                        continue;
                    }
                }
            } else {
                if(isset($schedulesAvailable[$key])) {
                    $schedulesAvailable[$key] = $schedule;
                }
            }

            // Check if there is a limit of only one booking at time per aircraft
            if(!$this->RebuildVA->allowMultipleAircraftBookings()) {
                if(!$this->Aircrafts->isBooked($schedule['aircraftId'])) {
                    $schedulesAvailable[$key] = $schedule;
                } else {
                    unset($schedulesAvailable[$key]);
                    continue;
                }
            } else {
                if(isset($schedulesAvailable[$key])) {
                    $schedulesAvailable[$key] = $schedule;
                }
            }

            // Check if there is a limit of only one booking at time per pilot
            if(!$this->RebuildVA->allowMultiplePilotBookings()) {   
                if(!$this->Pilots->hasBookedFlight($this->session->userdata('pilotId'))) {
                    $schedulesAvailable[$key] = $schedule;
                } else {
                    unset($schedulesAvailable[$key]);
                    continue;
                }
            } else {
                if(isset($schedulesAvailable[$key])) {
                    $schedulesAvailable[$key] = $schedule;
                }
            }
        }
    } else {
        $schedulesAvailable = $schedules;   
    }       

    return $schedulesAvailable;
}
```